# I have uv unwrapped a model. selected brush, texture and colour but failing to paint the body of the model

Tags: texture-painting

I have UV unwrapped a model in Blender 4.0. Have selected brush, texture and colour etc but failing to paint the body of the model. I can paint it in vertex paint mode but failing to paint in texture paint.

[image]

[![][2]][2]

In UV unwrapped screen it shows the strokes are getting printed on the frame below the unwrapped parts.

Any clue what is missing?
I am not using cycle. Switching to Material preview mode is also not helping.

Comment: If you are in Cycles you won't see anything in Rendered preview mode, you need to switch to Material preview mode then switch back. If it's not the problem, please pack your image and share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: No, I am not using Cycle. And switching modes is not helping. Tried sharing the file in compressed version. but it's bigger than allowed limit of 30mb. Tried remeshing to low poly but  then it is losing details. Not sure how to pack it in 30mb. Any suggestion ?

Comment: Use another platform like workupload

Answer (score 0):

The Texture paint can only be done in the Material Preview or Workbench modes, and to see the result in Cycles you will first need to save the image to disk for the result to be visible in Render view.